# While Loop in TSQL with Sum totals

Tags: sql

I have the following TSQL Statement, I am trying to figure out how I can keep getting the results (100 rows at a time), store them in a variable (as I will have to add the totals after each select) and continue to select in a while loop until no more records are found and then return the variable totals to the calling function.

```
SELECT [OrderUser].OrderUserId, ISNULL(SUM(total.FileSize), 0), ISNULL(SUM(total.CompressedFileSize), 0)
FROM 
(
 SELECT DISTINCT TOP(100) ProductSize.OrderUserId, ProductSize.FileInfoId, 
 CAST(ProductSize.FileSize AS BIGINT) AS FileSize, 
 CAST(ProductSize.CompressedFileSize AS BIGINT) AS CompressedFileSize
 FROM ProductSize WITH (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN [Version] ON ProductSize.VersionId = [Version].VersionId
) AS total RIGHT OUTER JOIN [OrderUser] WITH (NOLOCK) ON total.OrderUserId = [OrderUser].OrderUserId
WHERE NOT ([OrderUser].isCustomer = 1 AND [OrderUser].isEndOrderUser = 0 OR [OrderUser].isLocation = 1) 
AND [OrderUser].OrderUserId = 1
GROUP BY [OrderUser].OrderUserId
```

Comment: Why are you breaking them into batches of 100 if all you are doing is summing them? Or do you need the sum for each batch of 100 rows individually?

Comment: Which version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: I am using SQL 2005.

I want to do the sum in batches so that I don't cream the SQL server as this table contains 10-30million records

Comment: Have you tested a simple aggregate? While 10-30M rows may be a lot, I don't know that it will "cream" a decent server. It depends a lot on your indexing, etc. It's also usually a good idea not to code for a performance problem that you aren't experiencing until you've confirmed that you actually will have it.

Comment: Tom H, if you posted that as an answer, I'd upvote it. Sounds like the whole table has to be scanned to produce the desired results, and I'd have to think that breaking this scan into chunks would require more resources than just scanning the entire table in a single pass, NOLOCK or no.

Comment: I think you're going to end up creaming it a lot more as you're going to keep needing to rerun the same query and then starting at the right row number! Is there some other way you can partition the calculation e.g. by OrderUserId? (though I agree with Tom/Philip above)

Comment: Jeff Atwood previously discussed something about how breaking up big statements into all small ones is one of the reasons why stackoverflow can have several db queries on a single page view.  Can the query be re-written without the inner select?

Comment: I have to do this for multiple orderuserid, would you guys suggest changing the above statement to 1 query and remove the OrderUserId = 1 so that it returns for all users in one statement?

Comment: @RPS Definitely I think you should avoid partitioning by row number because (at the very least on the last batch) it might just end up calculating the whole result set then filtering it making the whole exercise pretty futile! Partitioning by OrderUserId might be reasonable dependant upon what indexes you have but have a look at the estimated execution plan to check that it isn't just going to end up doing a scan of the whole big table anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the clustered index, if its by numbered id, then use the code below. If its by date, go in 10 - 60 minute increments. keep an eye on performance of other things, but the lovely part of this code is you can start and stop at anytime if you push the results to permanent temp table (real table, just temp)

Here's a sample:

```
declare @count int
Declare @batch int
declare @max int

create table #temp (id int identity(1,1) primary key, Batch int, value int)


select @max = max(OrderUserId), @count = 0, @batch = 1000 from table

while (@count < @max)
begin

insert into #temp (batch,value)
select @count, Sum(stuffs)
from table
where orderId >= @count
 and orderid < @count + @batch

Set @count = @count + @batch

waitfor delay ('00:00:01')
Raiserror('On Batch %d',0,1,@Count) with nowait /* Will print progess */
end
```